# diverting the stdin when ssh-ing to another machine from python

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to use SSH as a socks proxy to another machine, then ask the user if he wants to proceed.
so I use:

```
proxy_cmd = "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -i " + key_filename + ' -D 9998 ubuntu@' + ip_address    
subprocess.Popen(proxy_cmd, shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if not raw_input('would you like to proceed?(y)')=='y':
    sys.exit()
```

and I get:

```
IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I assume that's because the ssh is open and it is capturing stdin or something. I just don't know how to bypass this (I have no need to send input to the ssh, I just want it open for Selenium to use later)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `stdin` available to your Python program, then you'll have to redirect `stdin` for the `ssh` process even if you have no intention of using it, with something like...

```
subprocess.Popen(proxy_cmd,
                 shell=True,
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that the `subprocess` module will retain a reference to the `Popen` object in the `subprocess._active` list, but you may also want to bind the resulting `Popen` object to a variable so you can perform operations on it later.